# APK Expansion Files: Specifying library path in Android Studio (Windows)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, apk-expansion-files

I am on Android Studio (Windows 10). I have been trying to follow the steps in https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html but am stuck at the section "Preparing to use the Downloader Library". I have downloaded and installed Google Play License Library and Google Play Downloader Library. I have created the corresponding modules. But when I go to Module Settings and specify the path to the Library Repository, I get errors and when I open up Module Settings again, the Library Repository field remains blank. The error I get are :

```
10:23:57 PM IncorrectOperationException: Error while applying changes: cannot create file from text: C:\Users\n56\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\market_apk_expansion\downloader_library\
10:36:23 PM IncorrectOperationException: Error while applying changes: cannot create file from text: C:\Users\n56\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\market_licensing\library\
```

And the library repository paths I specified are :

```
C:\Users\n56\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\market_apk_expansion\downloader_library
C:\Users\n56\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\market_licensing\library\
```

I have tried various things like escaping the backslashes, importing the modules instead of clicking New Modules but to no available.

Would be grateful for any help. TIA.

Answer (score 8):

The documentation of this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) miss the reference of the *Android Manifes.xml* file on the path for each [android-library](/questions/tagged/android-library).

The correct path for each library are:

**Google Play License Library**
`<sdk>/extras/google/play_licensing/library/AndroidManifest.xml`

**Google Play Downloader Library**
`<sdk>/extras/google/play_apk_expansion/downloader_library/AndroidManifest.xml`

I noticed that on other [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html#lvl-setup) from Google where use the same library for setting up the *Licensing Verification Library*

[image: Tutorial for LVL]

[image: Android Library Repository]

> **ANSWER UPDATED:**
>   These previous method only reference one file of the whole library.
>   Actually I revert all this steps to use a library from [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle) whit all we need to use **Google Play License Library** and **Google Play Downloader Library** there is the link for the [repository](https://github.com/danikula/Google-Play-Expansion-File)

Answer (score 1):

I tried and made it work with below Tags in individual Module's build.gradle . flatDir is the key to solution. and for **Windows** based Android Studio,  the '\' needs to be escaped using double '\' backslashes.

```
repositories {

     flatDir {
          dirs "C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\extras\\google\\market_licensing"
     }
}
```

I am still learning, but I think it has something to do with flatDirs container which should be child of repositories container.

it is now showing up a bit different but the Gradle Sync just works.

[image: Project Structure Dialog]